# Textview becomes UpperCase after applying theme?

Tags: android, themes

I am newbie to android and have question regarding Theme.

I have applied **Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar** for my activity after applying this my **Textview** are changed based on the new material design theme and my question is why my Textview becomes UpperCase after applying and **Spinner** component becomes transparent in background?

```
<style name="CustomTeme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/primary_color</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">false</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBar">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowActionBarOverlay">true</item>
    <item name="android:activatedBackgroundIndicator">@drawable/list_activated_background</item>
</style>
```

Comment: Show your detail code for it .

Comment: Can I see style.xml file

Comment: I posted my styles

Comment: please post your xml layout code where you are using "CustomTeme" style

Comment: @kamalverma i applied directly in manifest

Answer (score 0):

**Use this in style.xml**

```
  <item name="android:textAllCaps">false</item>
```